# Select line in current python script and run them in python interpreter?

Tags: python, spacevim

I am new to SpaceVim and would like to use it to develop in python.
I am actually new to non GUI IDE, which is why I am starting with SpaceVim instead of vanilla NeoVim.

This said, I would like to run part of a script (only part of it) into a terminal to check if the code is working as intended.
Should I open an external terminal, start python, and copy/past my code to it?

SpaceVim states how to run the full python script, `SPC l r`
but not how to select lines to only run those.

Please, how could I do that?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: How about starting `ipython` and then copying and pasting your code.

Comment: Well, the question, is there a way doing it while staying in SpaceVim?